# How to check if json data has empty value or not in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a CRUD application in Django.
and want to know how I can check if the input JSON data is empty or not
for example:
I am getting a JSON input dictionary as

```
{'status':'abc','name':'xyz','address':'abc@123','city':'abc'}etc
```

I want to check if name is not empty and city is not empty.
I don't want a required field in model but to handle the JSON data.
If the JSON input is not valid i.e if username and email is valid then save the data into database else give a warning 400.

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Location
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields= '__all__'
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def locationAdd(request):
    serializer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response("data entered successfully")
    else:
        return Response("data entered is not valid")
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

models.py

```
class Location(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    postalCode = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Comment: This is a rest_framework view? Can you add the code for your view and serializer? Usually you would have a serializer that validates the incoming data

Comment: Can you add the `Location` model too? You probably have to add custom fields to your serializer

Comment: The fields in your model are required anyway, the serializer shouldn't accept null values for those fields

Comment: but sir lets suppose I have mentioned all model fields as null=True, how can I then handle the JSON data and check if value is not empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most appropriate way would be to add `extra_kwrgs` in the `Meta` class of your serilalizer.

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = ['name', 'city']
        extra_kwrgs = {
            'name' : {
                'required' : True
            },
            'city' : {
                'required' : True
            }
        }
```

If you want to implement some other type of validation or manipulation to the particular field then you can use `def validate_<field_name>` in your serializer.

Here is how it can be implemented -

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Location
        fields = ['name', 'city']
        extra_kwrgs = {
            'name' : {
                'required' : True
            },
            'city' : {
                'required' : True
            }
        }

    def validate_name(self, name):

        """
        This method is going to verify if the `name` string contains of all white spaces.
        """

        if name.isspace():

            raise serializer.ValidationError('The name field contain only spaces and no characters.')

        return name
```

You will also have to modify your view to make it work with your serializer's configuration.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def locationAdd(request):
    serializer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response("data entered successfully")
```

In your views this line `serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)` will terminate the execution and will raise the validation errors if the provided data is not correct.

Answer (score 0):

For fields that you want to make required even though they are not in your model you can define a custom field on the serializer that is required to override the generated fields

```
class LocationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    city = serializers.CharField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Location
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in the views.py file. Just check like below before calling the serializer

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def locationAdd(request):

    if len(request.data.get('username')) == 0 and len(request.data.get('email')) == 0:
        return Response(status=400)

    serializer = LocationSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response("data entered successfully")
    else:
        return Response("data entered is not valid")
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

You can add any validations on your request data like this.

Answer (score -1):

As much as validation in the api backend is reasonable and should always be there for defensive measures, I would also consider doing a check for an empty form on the frontend. That way you dont send unecessary http requests to the backend.